# No matching package named 'evm-gasometer found'

Tags: runtime-upgrade, evm, upgrade

My node is on the substrate branch polkadot-v0.9.19. I have bumped it to polkadot-v0.9.22. After bumping the version I am trying to build the node in release mode using the following command.

```
cargo build --release
```

Doing so gave me the following error.

```
error: failed to select a version for `signature`.
    ... required by package `ecdsa v0.13.3`
    ... which satisfies dependency `ecdsa-core = "^0.13"` of package `k256 v0.10.4`
    ... which satisfies dependency `k256 = "^0.10.4"` of package `frame-support v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.22#616d33ea)`
    (/mnt/d/rrr/my-node-rrr/node/runtime)`
    ... which satisfies path dependency `mychain-runtime` (locked to 4.0.0) of package `mychain-cli v4.0.0 (/mnt/d/rrr/my-node-rrr/node/cli)`
versions that meet the requirements `>=1.3.1, <1.5` are: 1.4.0, 1.3.2, 1.3.1

all possible versions conflict with previously selected packages.

  previously selected package `signature v1.5.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `signature = ">=1.3.1"` (locked to 1.5.0) of package `ed25519 v1.5.2`
    ... which satisfies dependency `ed25519 = "^1"` (locked to 1.5.2) of package `ed25519-dalek v1.0.1`
    ... which satisfies dependency `ed25519-dalek = "^1.0.1"` (locked to 1.0.1) of package `libp2p-core v0.32.1`
    ... which satisfies dependency `libp2p-core = "^0.32.1"` of package `libp2p v0.44.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `libp2p = "^0.44.0"` of package `sc-authority-discovery v0.10.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=polkadot-v0.9.22#616d33ea)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `sc-authority-discovery` of package `mychain-cli v4.0.0 (/mnt/d/rrr/my-node-rrr/node/cli)`

failed to select a version for `signature` which could resolve this conflict
```

At this point, i decided to update the dependencies using

```
cargo update
```

and got the following error

```
 Updating crates.io index
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/paritytech/substrate`
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/rust-blockchain/evm`
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/paritytech/frontier`
error: no matching package named `evm-gasometer` found
location searched: https://github.com/rust-blockchain/evm?branch=master
required by package `evm-tracing-events v0.1.0 (/mnt/d/rrr/my-node-rrr/primitives/rpc/evm-tracing-events)`
```

How do I resolve this issue? There is no package named 'evm-gasometer' in the master branch of evm repo. What is the branch I should be using? How do i fix this so that the node builds successfully.

I have a rust toolchain file with the following contents.

```
[toolchain]
channel = "nightly-2023-11-01-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"
components = [ "rustfmt", "clippy" ]
targets = [ "wasm32-unknown-unknown" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `cargo build --release --locked`